# Vuex - Cloned state into data object property, can't delete array item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I've cloned my state from Vuex to an array in my component, `data()`. My problem is when I'm trying to remove the first item in the array from my clone with `shift()`and also add it back with `unshift()` I get this error msg:

> [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

How can I delete something in my cloned state that's not effects the actually state itself?

**Saving/cloning**

```
    beforeMount () {
        this.traningArea = this.stateExercises
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            userStore: state => state.userStore,
            tsStore: state => state.trainingSchemeStore
        }),
        stateExercises () {
            return this.tsStore.schemeExercises
        }
    }
```

**Trying to run `shift()` on click and `unshift()` if user click again**

```
this.traningArea[0].shift()
this.traningArea[0].unshift(obj)
```

And it's here I've got this error.

**STATE**

```
const state = {
    trainings: []
}

const actions = {
    getTrainingExercise: ({commit}, ids) => {
        var payload = {
           'trainings_id': ids
        }

        return Vue.http.post(getTrainingsById, payload, 
        {headers: getHeader()})
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                commit('SET_TERL', response.body.data)
            }
        })
  },

const mutations = {
    SET_TERL(state, trainings) {
       state.trainings.push(trainings)
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the store object

Comment: I've updated now

Comment: you could add function in your mutations object to handle that operation

Comment: Can you give me an example on that function? How it should look and so on.. I'm pretty lost here ^^

Comment: so provide me  your data object and methods

Comment: I can't, it's over 150 lines code .. It's okey if you just writing dummy data/methods just so I can get a hang of this problem :)

Comment: i need only that properties and methods concerned by your removing operation

Comment: Yea, and that's the problem.. It's not easy to get only that part. Call it whatever you want to, the name of the props and methods I will understand, only I need is how you will solve this problem, not what something is called or named it dosen't matter if you know what Im saying ^^

Answer (score 1):

i hope that i don't misunderstand you, so i think that the solution would be like this :

```
  const mutations = {
      SET_TERL(state, trainings) {
       state.trainings.push(trainings)
      },
       SHIFT(state, index) {
       state.trainings[index].shift() 
      },
     UNSHIFT(state, index,obj) {
       state.trainings[index].unshift(obj) 
      }
   }
```

and when you call the method :

```
 this.tsStore.commit("SHIFT",0);
```

or

```
  this.tsStore.commit("UNSHIFT",0,obj);
```

Comment: I will give this a try right away! Same operations is in my component instead, maybe it will work if I moved it to the `mutations`, thanks man. I'll let you know if it worked :)

Comment: I've got `this.tsStore.commit("SHIFT",0) is not a function`

Comment: so try `this.$store.commit ...`

Comment: It's working but now I'm deleting/adding from the state, I've cloned my state into an data prop so I can use that to remove and adding at the same time the state is listning into the view.

Comment: i could not figure out what the new problem?

Comment: I want to use `this.traningArea` with `shift/unshift` and not the state itself.

Comment: i think they are bound and when you try to modify one the other one will be affected

Comment: Okey, so you can't really unbound so the state will not be effected when I'm deleting an item? If that is the case this was the last time I'm using Vue in my Front End.

Comment: sorry, they are not bound if you're using them like `traningArea:this.$store.state.trainings`

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: in this way i can't help you efficiently, try to paste your code in https://pastebin.com/  and give me the link

Comment: Do you have Slack?